# How To Make a PHP Script Synchronously Update From Terminal Values

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, real-time-updates

Using a Raspberry Pi I created a script which loads the CPU Temperature of the Pi through an Apache Server onto the Browser.

```
<?php
$temp = exec('vcgencmd measure_temp');

$temp = str_replace('temp=','',$temp);
$temp = str_replace('\'C','',$temp);

echo $temp;

?>
```

Using the code above I have to manually refresh the page to see the latest value.

It works fine but I'd like to know how I could set this up without having to refresh the browser all the time.

Within the Terminal on the Pi I was able to use the "watch" command which will give me the current value every 0.1 seconds.

But by executing this script, the browser will give me a blank page.

```
<?php
$temp = exec('watch -n 0.1 vcgencmd measure_temp');

$temp = str_replace('temp=','',$temp);
$temp = str_replace('\'C','',$temp);

echo $temp;

?>
```

Is there any way to make the script using the "watch" command work with the PHP Script? If not, is there any other way to make it refresh everytime the value changes in the terminal?

Note: *I am new to programming and using the Pi.*

I would really appreciate any helpful information!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no way to have PHP print new output to the page in place of what's already been printed as requested, a common workaround is to still have a PHP page that gives you the temperature, but to call it every x seconds with AJAX and dynamically update the page with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch wont work in your case, you can call jquery cdn from official website and then do this function. Do not forget to open console to see what comes back. **F12**

Add this into your php file.

```
if(isset($_GET)){

$temp = exec('vcgencmd measure_temp');

$temp = str_replace('temp=','',$temp);
$temp = str_replace('\'C','',$temp);

echo $temp;
}
```

Then into your index.html

```
 $(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000); // 1000 represents 1 second, free to change
    $.get('index.php', function(data) { // i assume your index.php in same folder with your html file.
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Made a bad edit on your question, apologies - I would recommend you use setInterval rather than setTimeout as you're doing now.

Comment: Yeah, but `setInterval()` is designed to do explicitly what you're trying to do. Not a huge deal in the end but this kind of thing may introduce some kind of problem in the future.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for helping me out! Unfortunately I still have some questions due to the fact that I’m a beginner to all of this. What you basically recommended is a jquery which will trigger the PHP every few seconds, is that correct? In my folder there’s also just the .php file. I didn’t use HTML. Is this needed? And if so, how could I connect both of these files? Last question would be, if I have to install jQuery on my Pi. Sorry for asking trivial questions like this and thank you once again!

Comment: @raspberry What this does is sends a request to a php page via JavaScript (JQuery) and the php returns everything it would have displayed in the form of html usually. It returns via JavaScript so you need to handle it and put it back into your webpage. [Here's a quick tutorial on it.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm)

Comment: PHP and HTML go hand in hand, so you're likely using it without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a easier way to set this up.
What I wanted to do was not having to manually refresh the page in order to get the current temperature values.

The answers above were correct but I wasn't able to set it up by myself so I figured out I can add a header and refresh into my PHP script which will make the page refresh every second (or whatever timeframe is needed).

The code looks like this now:

```
<?php header('refresh: 1');
$temp = exec('vcgencmd measure_temp');

$temp = str_replace('temp=','',$temp);
$temp = str_replace('\'C','',$temp);

echo $temp;

?>
```

Thank you to everyone who was trying to help me!